# How to find HTML elements that match a certain string, using HtmlUnitDriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, htmlunit-driver

I wuold find all HTML element in a page that math a certain string like, for example,
`<form action=/ method="GET">`, using HtmlUnitDriver (java).

What I would do is a web application, that takes in inputs two parameters:

- url to search for
- a pattern

I have this piece of java code:

```
HtmlUnitDriver browser = new HtmlUnitDriver(true);
browser.get(urlParamter);
List<WebElement> result = //find all HTML elements that match a certain pattern.
```

Now suppose I'm looking for some elements in this page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">
    </form>

    <form id="form2">
    </form>

    <p class="test"></p>
    <p class="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If I search for the string `<form id="form1">` I would get the first form element, instead if I search for `<p class="test">` I would get the two paragraph elements.
Is it possible?
All the suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I'm at the begginning; honestly, I would not know where to start; I tried with xpath, but without result (i'm at the beginning). Where could  I search for a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try using findElements() instead of findElement() with the xpath matching your text. Example below.

```
List<WebElement> result = browser.findElements(By.xpath("//[contains(text(),'yourtext')]"));
```